# Combining two lines of cmd and adding "if" condition, is it possible?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Below I have two lines of code I want to combine into one and add an if condition, so that if the laptop matches "LAP" then carry out the rest of the command, but if "LAP" is not matching, then it would stop running altogether.

```
hostname >>  \\MyLap\c$\WhoAreYouDevice\ThisDeviceIs.txt
ipconfig | find "172" /i >>  \\MyLap\c$\WhoAreYouDevice\ThisDeviceIs.txt
```

I have never written in CMD/Batch, so I am really unsure how to do it. but business requires me to do it quite soon. I'm afraid Powershell is not an option, I'm okay with powershell and can do it there, but can't use it for this task.

My expected outcome would be
1 single txt file with the below inside it:

LAP

IPv4 Address

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have taken a look at your other questions, and I absolutely do not believe that you have not got the capacity to search for something, and try to adapt it as necessary. This is not a code writing or tutorial service, help yourself, before asking for it from others. Even in the case that you've never written in cmd/batch, there's noting stopping you from using PowerShell and running it either as a `-File` or a `-Command` from within a batch file or the Command Prompt.

Comment: use [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html): `hostname|find "LAP" && ipconfig|find " 172." >>file.txt`

Comment: Thank you for the link, it was useful, I also soon figured out I cannot use hostname with what I am trying to achieve so I found another way

Answer (score 0):

The below code got me what I needed:

```
echo %computername% >> \\MyLap\c$\WhoAreYouDevice\ThisDeviceIs.txt && ipconfig | find "172" >> \\MyLap\c$\WhoAreYouDevice\ThisDeviceIs.txt
```